# ハードコードされた即値（文字列、整数、浮動小数）を洗い出したい

Tags: c#

C#です。
あるプログラムを移植することになって、その前段階としてハードコードした即値を洗い出したいといわれました。
目視で洗い出そうとするとファイル数が400近くあるのでかなり手間ですし、抜け漏れがでそうです。
できればプログラムで自動で洗い出したいです。
最初は正規表現のパターンマッチでやろうとしたのですが、
かなり複雑な条件になりそうで根本的に無理筋な気がしてきています。
できればC#の構文解析を行い、リテラルをピンポイントで抜き出したいです。
そのような目的に利用できるツールやライブラリはないでしょうか。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: ソースコードが400近くあるとのことで洗い出しは大変でしょうが、仮に即値をピックアップできたとして大量になるでしょう。得られたリストを見て呆然とするだけのような気がしますが、得られた後のロードマップは描けているのでしょうか？

Comment: すいません、後のロードマップは私は描けてませんがPMが何とかしてくれると信じています。下っ端の私はとりあえず手を動かすことに専念します。

Comment: 一応リテラルは抜き出せました。リテラルは38163個ありました。リストを見て呆然としていますT△T

Answer (score 7, accepted):

C#のコンパイラーは近年オープンソース化されており(**.NET Compiler Platform** = **Roslyn**)、コード分析や自動修正のルールもSDKのクラスを使用すれば比較的容易に作成できるようになりました。

ですので定数の抽出程度であれば

1. [.NET Compiler Platform SDK](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/)をインストールする
2. Analyzer With Code Fixプロジェクトを作成する
3. `DiagnosticAnalyzer`の`Initialize`メソッドで`RegisterSyntaxNodeAction`を呼びだしてコールバックを登録する
4. コールバック関数内で引数のノードが対象かどうかを判定し、対象であれば`ReportDiagnostic`メソッドを実行する。

という手順で簡単にVisual Studioのエラーリストに情報を表示することができます。
また`CodeFixProvider`でコードの自動修正を定義することもできます。

Comment: すいません。
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.NETCompilerPlatformSDK
からRoslyn SDK.vsixをダウンロードしてインストールしたのですが、
プロジェクト作成時のテンプレートでAnalyzer With Code Fixがでてきません。
何か他にインストールする必要があるのでしょうか

Comment: @Jogenara 現在はDiagnostic with Code Fix (NuGet + VSIX)という名称のようです。

Comment: すいません、開発環境が会社なので休み中確認できませんでした。
いま確認したところ、
VSIX Projectと、
Download the .NET Compiler Platform SDK
というテンプレートがあるのですが、他にそれらしいテンプレートはありませでした。

Comment: すいません、.net frameworkのバージョンを4.6にするといいみたいです。

Comment: やりたかったことはほぼできました。ありがとうございました。